# Cannot see go.sum after initializing backend of project

Tags: go

I am trying to make a simple Chat app using Golang in order to better understand the application. The tutorial I am following asks to initialize go.sum. After running the following commands, I only see go.mod

```
go install golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest
go mod init github.com/TutorialEdge/realtime-chat-go-react
```

How can I try to resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance!

I looked into possible version errors, but I can't really find a fix. I still can only see go.mod

Comment: There is no issue. go.sum is managed automatically. Consider consulting a better tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you are referring to is a bit dated in content. In current Go, go.sum is managed by the `go mod tidy` command.